# Data synchronization between AWS Cognito and java back-end

Tags: java, angular, amazon-cognito

I am building a web app with following stack:
- Cognito User Pool
- Angular 2 app hosted on S3
- ApiGateway
- Elastic Beanstalk with Spring boot backend
- Amazon RDS

Sign-up and sign in seem to work fine with Cognito, however what I fail to understand is how to synch user attributes from Cognito User Pool with my backend, i.e when user is registered his data is stored in Cognito, but I want to store his data (id, email, phone, address, etc) additionally in DB. When user changes his data, I want to as well reflect these changes in DB.

I thought, listening for Cognito events and using Lambda functions to do data sync is the way to go, but would it be possible to test this locally?

I am wondering if there is a better, more straightforward approach?

For example: may be it is better to parse JWT and get user id and retrieve user data with some kind of Cognito Server side API? But I wasn't able to find appropriate API. Would this approach even make sense?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad but think you can indeed use the [`cognitosync`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitosync) java sdk to access a user's data serverside like done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154025/how-to-access-dataset-of-an-identity-in-cognito-federated-identities-from-lambda I'd try not to duplicate the data though

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But I still would need to save user uuid (identity id), because I would have some cases where data would be required, when user is not logged in. So how should I store that?

Comment: Yes, the cognito generated identityId is meant to be your reference for a user since it won't change when users change their account data. You can save it in databases where appropriate, e.g. as primary key for user associated data, in like the posted-by column for a forum, etc. You'll still have to think about clean up if users go away or accounts merge

Comment: That is clear how to use the id :) It is not clear WHEN to post it to server. 
1. After successful registration as a separate POST request?

Comment: That is no so simple but boils down to: when your usecase needs it :)

Comment: Hm, there are many use cases, which would require user info, of a user who is not logged in - reports, user profile views by other user, search etc. So, I think it should be there from the very beginning (as User entry for new user is usually created, when user registers). But OK, I see there is no standard approach.